# Using Log4cxx in CMake

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I try to use log4cxx in my project. I installed log4cxx:

```
sudo apt-get install liblog4cxx-dev
```

But, when I use `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(log4cxx)
```

It gives an error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "log4cxx" with any
of the following names:

log4cxxConfig.cmake
log4cxx-config.cmake
```

I think it is missing log4cxxConfig.cmake. But I don;t know how to fix it.

Comment: Old question, but I stumbled upon this and was confused because it DID WORK. `apt install liblog4cxx-dev` and then `find_package(log4cxx REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(... log4cxx)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a file named "FindLog4cxx.cmake".

I found the following on at Kitware's GitHub repository:
https://github.com/Kitware/vibrant/blob/master/CMake/FindLog4cxx.cmake

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing but was confused about what exactly to do with the file.

Here is additional detail with instructions for linux

```
cd myproject
mkdir -p CMakeModules
cd CMakeModules
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kitware/vibrant/master/CMake/FindLog4cxx.cmake
```

Then add these two lines to your top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
find_package(Log4cxx REQUIRED)'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)    
project(test_log4cxx VERSION 0.1.0)         
                                                                                              
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)                                        
find_package(Log4cxx QUIET)                                                                                          
                                                                                       
add_executable(main main.cpp)                                                                                        
include_directories(${LOG4CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})                                                                         
target_link_libraries(main ${LOG4CXX_LIBRARIES})
```